# Error on the calculation of area of a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, error-analysis

I am currently writing an investigation for my high school diploma, and I am a little rusty on uncertainties and error propagation. So I was wondering whether I could get some help on a doubt I had.

In my experiment, I investigate the relationship that exists between the parachute vent hole radius and the drop time. I have already collected the data, and I'm doing my error analysis. Nevertheless I was wondering the formula for uncertainty of the area of the parachute.

The regular formula I have established to calculate the area of the parachute is:
$A=\pi (r_t^2-r_v^2)$, where $r_t$ is the total radius of the circular parachute and $r_v$ is the radius of the vent.

My idea was that the error equation would be the following: $\delta A=\pi \ \delta(r_t^2-r_v^2)$, where $\delta(r_t^2-r_v^2)=\delta(r_t^2)-\delta(r_v^2)$ and $\delta(r_t^2)$ and/or $\delta(r_t^2)$ is simply the least count measurment of the ruler divided by 2, which in this case would be ± 0.05 cm.

Edit: After a suggestion by another member, the corrected formula stands as  $δA=π [2rδ(rt)+2rδ(rv)]$, though I am assuming it is not the best derivation that could be done.

Is this approach correct? Or does it warrant another completly different one, such as partial derivatives (note: I have taken calculus, but haven't done partial derivatives) or something similar?

Comment: The last few steps are wrong. $\delta(a-b)=\delta(a)+\delta(b)$ and $\delta(r^2)=2r\delta(r)$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent So the fixed formula would be $\delta A = \pi \ [2rδ(r_t) + 2rδ(r_v)]$?

Comment: This is at least reasonable; but did they ask you to add the squares of the uncertainties or did they ask you to add the uncertainties? Middle school physics does the latter, always, university physics does the former, always, and high school is in limbo, different schools do different things.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent It is a personal investigation, so I am in charge doing the uncertainties, I wasn't instructed directly on anything. Seeing as my aim is to be more rigorous, I had simply assumed that the better formula would be to add the squares of the uncertainties.

Comment: Edit: I found an online uncertaintly calculator which calculates it with the following formula: $\sqrt{4 \pi^2 \sigma_x^2 x^2+4 \pi^2 \sigma_y^2 y^2}$, where $x$ and $y$ are the 2 radii. Could anyone be so kind as to explain the derivation of such a formula and if it is better or worse than the one I found?

Comment: @MilesJarraGloekler You're looking for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification

Comment: @MilesJarraGloekler I provided an answer with the explanation of the RSS formula you found online

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes uncertainty is propagated from independent variables to a dependent variable using RSS (Root of the Sum of the Squares). This is usually a good way to express uncertainty, assuming that:

- the independent variables are **not correlated**: roughly speaking, and confusing (only here!!!) correlation and dependence, you can error/uncertainty on a variable doesn't influence the error/uncertainty on other variables;
- uncertainties are "small", since this process involves a linearization.

Let's show RSS for a 2-variable function, and do things properly (even if you explicitly stated that you haven't done partial derivatives yet), and then make (at least IMHO) a reasonable assumption.

**Basics of RSS.** Given a function $f(x, y)$, depending on two variables with uncertainty (here quantified with a variance) $\sigma^2_x$, $\sigma_y^2$. RSS gives us the uncertainty as
\begin{equation}
  \sigma_f^2 = \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)^2 (\overline{x},\overline{y}) \sigma_x^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2 (\overline{x},\overline{y}) \sigma_y^2 \ ,
\end{equation}
being $\overline{x}$, $\overline{y}$ the (average?) measure of the variables.

**Basics of partial derivatives.** A partial derivative of a function w.r.t. a variable is the ordinary derivative w.r.t. that variables, keeping all the other variables constant. Let's evaluate the partial derivatives your function $f(x,y) = \pi (x^2 - y^2)$, without being afraid of them!
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) & = \text{(Here $y$ is kept constant)} = 2 \pi x \\
  \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) & = \text{(Here $x$ is kept constant)} = -2 \pi y \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

**RSS applied to your problem.**
Applying the RSS to your problem we get
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \sigma_f^2 & = \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r_t} \right)^2 (\overline{r}_t,\overline{r}_v) \sigma_{r_t}^2 + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r_v} \right)^2 (\overline{r}_t,\overline{r}_v) \sigma_{r_v}^2 = \\
 & = \left( 2 \pi \overline{r}_t \right)^2 \sigma_{r_t}^2 +  \left( - 2 \pi r_t \right)^2 \sigma_{r_v}^2 = \\
 & = 4 \pi^2 \overline{r}_t^2 \, \sigma_{r_t}^2 + 4 \pi^2 \overline{r}_v^2 \, \sigma_{r_v}^2 \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
This is the estimate, given the uncertainties on the measurements on the two radii.

**Reasonable assumption.** If you use the same instrument to perform the measurements of these two radii, it's likely that the uncertainties are the same, $\sigma_r = \sigma_t$, and thus

\begin{equation}
\sigma_f^2 = 4 \pi^2 \left( \overline{r}_t^2 + \overline{r}_v^2 \right) \sigma_{r_v}^2
\end{equation}